# Is there a synonym for "top-class" you can use for chefs?

Tags: word-request

Is there a synonym for "top-class" you can use for chefs? I thought about "Michelin-starred", but that's too specific and not every "top-class" chef is "Michelin-starred" and "top-class" is too generic and can be used for other things than chefs. I am looking for an adjective, but maybe a noun that means "top-class chef" would do the job too.

Comment: If you start typing ***cordon bleu*** (French, "blue ribbon", as an "award" recognising top-class performance or product) into the Google search box, it'll suggest ***chef*** as a likely third word in the sequence.

Comment: I believe that technically "Michelin stars" are awarded to a resturant, not to a chef, and are not automatically transferred if the chef changes jobs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is very little wrong with the generic "top class"

> You will be served a meal prepared by a top class chef ...

There is an expression "[cordon bleu](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/cordon-bleu)"  meaning an excellent chef. There are a few problems with its use: It is a cliché, and over-use has tended to weaken its meaning. It tends to suggest chef who is skilled at classical French cooking, and it is now more usually used for a chef who trained at one of the various schools called "Le Cordon Bleu".

Given these problems, I'd not use "cordon bleu", and stick to the generic.